# AWS-SQL connection: The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I have created a MS-SQL inastance in AWS.

I am going to communicate with the instance via SQL Server Management Studio 2017. BUt I get error: "server was not found or was not accessible".

- I have created an instance in AWS and given the accessibility to public.
- I set the security group inbound to type:MS-SQL, port-range:1433, source:anywhere.
- I added db.cepigp4txnuv.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433 in the SQL Server Management Studio 2017 and set it to SQL Server Authentication.
- I have turned off firewall
- I have added port 1433 to windows firewall inbound/outbound

None of them solved the connection error.

Comment: This is just a bunch of hyperlinks. If you have information that is important to your question, include it in your question. Users are not going to be opening random links to Google mail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added all security groups to the instance and it worked. I am not sure if adding all groups is the right decision.

Answer (score 0):

Security Groups in AWS are egress and ingress rules applied to EC2 Instances.

You may also need to apply egress and ingress rules as Network ACLs on the Subnet(s) of your VPC. By default Network ACLs are fully open but yours may already be configured otherwise.

References:

- [Authorizing Inbound Traffic for Your Windows Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)
- [Network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html)

== edit 1 ==

Also check the Server Settings in the SQL Server Configuration tool that:

- The TCP/IP protocol is enabled. It starts out Disabled on SQL Server Developer edition and probably some others.
- The TCP/IP protocol is listening on port 1433 on all configured IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

You mentioned you checked Windows Firewall for tcp/1433, but re-check it if there were different ports used above. The first thing we do on our servers is to assign a random port over 1,024 and firewall it so that it's only accessible via localhost.

Comment: All settings are as per default. Network ACL: inbound/outbound : 100, all traffic, allow; *,all traffic, deny.